# Show <div> when e-mail is validated Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to show my div when the email isn't validated. And hide it when it is.

This is what I tried, but it isn't working.

```
$("#fes-email").on("change.validation keyup.validation", function () {
    var email = $(this).val(); 
    $("#fes-submit").prop("disabled", email.length == 0 || !isValidEmailAddress(email));
    $('#fes-form').submit(function () { 
        return !$("#fes-submit").is(':disabled') 
        $("#notification-container").show("slide");
    });
}).trigger('change.validation');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You exit the function before you show it.

```
$('#fes-form').submit(function () { 
    return !$("#fes-submit").is(':disabled')    <---exits function
    $("#notification-container").show("slide");  <-- will never be called
});
```

AND you have a BIGGER problem. On every single change you are binding a submit handler to the form. That is BAD. Take the submit handler OUT of the change event.

```js
(function() {

  var isValid = false;

  $("#fes-email").on("change.validation keyup.validation", function() {
    var email = $(this).val();
    isValid = email.length && isValidEmailAddress(email);
  }).trigger('change.validation');

  $('#fes-form').submit(function() {
    if (isValid) { 
        $("#notification-container").slideUp();
    } else { 
        $("#notification-container").slideDown();
    }
    return isValid;
  });

}());

function isValidEmailAddress(email) {
  var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return re.test(email);
}
```

```css
#notification-container {
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="fes-form">
  <label for="fes-email">Email</label>
  <input type="text" id="fes-email" name="fes-email" class="validation" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
<div id="notification-container">Invalid Email</div>
```

Comment: How do I get it called then?

Comment: Put it BEFORE the return.

Comment: Placed it above the return like you said, tried to hide it. But it didn't hide.

Comment: You are not hiding it, you are showing it. If you want to hide or show it, you need to use slideToogle(BOOLEAN)

Comment: It's not hiding my div though. Can there be another problem? I see the text blink.

Comment: Well is the :disbled check actually working? I would not do it that way.

Comment: It is. The text gets div gets triggered and the text blinks but for some reason still stays visible.

Comment: You see my changes? try that

Comment: Do you have other code? It is working for me when I ran a test.

Comment: Not really. The function to validate the email address. I have the css from the div.